# Should Gradle make a per project local copy of JAR-s from mavenLocal()?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, dependencies

I have some library Gradle Java projects that I am currently publishing to my local Maven repositoty with the `publishToMavenLocal` task.  I can look for a library called `base` file in my local `.m2\repository\...` area, and *find* it as (say):

- `... lib\base\08.00.003-SNAPSHOT\`**`base-08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar`**

A client project, `socket_listener` uses `base` and declares the local repository as shown.  This project build fine and runs successfully from the Gradle command line.

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    jcenter()
}

//  later in the file...
//
assemble.dependsOn      distDirectory
```

Run ...

```
gradle socket_listener:run 
   :
       lots of logger output
   :
```

The `socket_listener` project creates a `dist` directory for the `socket_listener.jar` assembly with requried dependencies in a `lib/*` folder for dependencies with this:

```
task distDirectory( type: Copy ) {
    into 'dist'
    from jar
    from 'src/dist'
    into( 'lib' )
    {
        from configurations.runtime
    }
}
```

Which I also thought was OK until I tried to run my listener project from the command line; it fails thus.

```
 cd socket_listener\dist
 java -jar SocketListener.jar
```

Gives error (manifest setting below):

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class example.app.cmd.SocketListener
```

And when I inspected the `lib/` folder -- NO `base-08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar` was to be found.  None of the `mavenLocal` JAR files are in `lib/`.  This is my first hurdle, the program won't work without those `mavenLocal` JAR-s.

As well manifest settings in gradle are just copies from other working projects.

```
mainClassName = 'example.app.cmd.SocketListener'

    :

jar
{
    manifest
    {
        attributes( "Main-Class":       mainClassName )
        attributes( "Application-Name": "socket_listener" )
        attributes( "Class-Path":       'lib/' + ( configurations.runtime.collect { it.getName() }.join(' lib/') ) )
        attributes( "Codebase":         "*" )
        attributes( "Permissions":      "all-permissions" )
    }
}
```

That should not be problem #2.

Upon discovering **`base-08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar`** missing-in-action from the `lib/` directory, I set about to find that file.  Guess what?

The ONLY place I found the JAR file is in the Maven repositor, viz.:

```
dir /s/b  d:\*08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar
d:\.rep\.m2\repository\local\lib\driver_model\08.00.003-SNAPSHOT\driver_model-08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar
d:\.rep\.m2\repository\local\lib\base\08.00.003-SNAPSHOT\base-08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar

dir /s/b  d:\*08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar
File Not Found
```

Which is kind of same as a linux `find / -name "*08.00.003-SNAPSHOT.jar"` command.  That's every directory on the PC, directly after a successful

```
gradle socket_listener:build -x test --refresh-dependencies
gradle socket_listener:run
```

And ensuring the latest dependencies loaded.  From my little experiemtal result it is quite clear that the project's Gradle build is using the library JAR-s directly from the repository -- For **build**, for **run**, for **test**.

- This is completly *UNEXPECTED* ...

My collegues and I feel sure that other locally build artefacts were cached or at least saved locally to a  `dist/` folder.  In ths example the `base` JAR is not copied anywhere.

Can I force the `mavenLocal` assets to be (at least) copied into the `lib/` folder and be ready for use?

In addition, looking into the contents of the current SocketListener.jar's **manifest** I am not convinced that ***all*** requisite JAR files have been loaded.  For a start, things that my `base` JAR depends are also will be missing.  I feel that other up-stream dependencies are NOT there either.

What is the usual process to ensure all dependencies are gathered for a build and for running a Java command line app from ***both*** Gradle and the command line prompt??

Is it normal to use the maven repository like that?

How can it be overridden?

Answer (score 0):

- I have discovered that `configurations.runtime` is not what I need.
- The *`from`* clause in the **`distDirectory`** task should

As follows

```
 task distDirectory( type: Copy ) {
     into 'dist'
     from jar
     from 'src/dist'
     into( 'lib' )
     {
         from configurations.from configurations.runtimeClasspath
     }
 }
```

- `runtimeClasspath` gives me all the direct dependencies for `socket_listener`.

I am unsure 'how' the `build.gradle` I took that model from performs for other projects.  I expect those projects make an installer and don't need to use that `dist/` folder explicitly.

Also, afer some testing and experimentation it is confirmed that this JAR won't run unless the Manifest also uses `runtimeClasspath` collection (or  `compileClasspath`), viz.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes( "Main-Class": mainClassName )
        attributes( "Application-Name": "socket_listener" )
        attributes( "Class-Path": 'lib/' + ( configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.getName() }.join(' lib/') ) )
        attributes( "Codebase": "*" )
        attributes( "Permissions": "all-permissions" )
    }
}
```

However, I suspect that is Not Always the case.  The main class `SocketListener` probably needs an absent JAR in the `runtimeClasspath` to load.  Other programs may load fine.  They may fall over with a stacktrace that will identify were look.  Or just work OK.

Would that the java launcher would be as *nice*.

Btw, I didn't find ClassPath mentioned in any of the many 'simple Gradle examples` for making a JAR that runs outh there the web.  While you can build without a ClassPath, it is better to have one for real-world use *imho*.

On to practical matters.  This problem arose because the `build.gradle` file in question uses: **`implementation`**`( ... )` dependency specifications instead of:`compile( ... )` dependencies.

I was able to confirm this by moving one dependency from an `implementation` to a `compile` line and use the `runtime` collection.  The resulting JAR and `lib/` have the module I moved.

I leave which one you use to the reader.  Here's some references:

- [Recognizing API and implementation dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) ([The Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph))
- [API and implementation separation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) (java plugin)
- [Declaring a concrete version of a dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:declaring_dependency_with_version) ([Declaring Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html))